# npm module "csv-db" not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, npm

I'm trying to use a "lightweight offline database", which stores data in .csv files. Documentation to the module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-db
The module seems not to work for me, tried everything. my actual code is:

**index.js**:

```
const CsvDb = require('csv-db');
const db = new CsvDb("test_db.csv");

(async () => {
    const db = await db.get();
    await db.insert({
            id: 3,
            title: "Obj3Title."
        })
        .then((data) => console.log(data), (err) => console.log(err));
})();
```

**test_db.csv**: (lies in same directory as index.js)

```
id;title;
1;Obj1Title;
2;Obj2Title;
```

So i get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: db is not defined
```

i also tried the following as path in "new CsvDb(...)" getting the same error:

```
const db = new CsvDb(__dirname + "\\test_db.csv");
const db = new CsvDb("./test_db.csv");
```

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you are doing wrong.

You are re-assigning value to the constant **"db"**.

Here's what you should be doing:

```
const CsvDb = require('csv-db');
const csvDbInstance = new CsvDb("test_db.csv");

(async () => {
    const db = await csvDbInstance.get();
    await db.insert({
            id: 3,
            title: "Obj3Title."
        })
        .then((data) => console.log(data), (err) => console.log(err));
})();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: tanks for your reply!
tried your version but "db" is still "not available" and test_db.csv is still in the same state, no additions.

Comment: the error is, that "db" has still no value after the
const db = await csvDbInstance.get(); 
line, and the db.insert function doesn't add the object with id:3 and title:"Obj3Title" because of "db" being nothing while assignment

Comment: try without async

Comment: still no luck, db becomes a pending promise with an undefined promise-value